# Why does gdb not show the error context when I run gdb /bin/ls?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

Why does gdb not show the error context when I run gdb /bin/ls ?

I implemented my malloc using the malloc-tutorial (https://danluu.com/malloc-tutorial/), compiled it in a shared library and I want to replace the current malloc on system with my malloc using LD_PRELOAD to practice debugging.
But when I run it through gdb, I can't see the detailed error context like in the tutorial. Why?

My:

```
$  gdb /usr/bin/ls
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/ls...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/2f/15ad836be3339dec0e2e6a3c637e08e48aacbd.debug...
(gdb) set environment LD_PRELOAD=/home/ays/work/malloc-tutorial/malloc.so
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/ls
During startup program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
(gdb) list
1435    src/ls.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

In tutorial:

```
$ gdb /bin/ls
(gdb) set environment LD_PRELOAD=./malloc.so
(gdb) run
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bd7dbd in free (ptr=0x0) at malloc.c:113
113       assert(block_ptr->free == 0);
```

I noticed that when I run `gdb /bin/ls`, the symbols are read from `usr/lib/debug/...`. Is this ok?

```
gdb /bin/ls
Reading symbols from /bin/ls...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/2f/15ad836be3339dec0e2e6a3c637e08e48aacbd.debug...
```

If I need source code besides debug symbols, how do I install it properly?

By the way, it is not mentioned here (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash) that I need to install the source code for debug.

Here some info about my coreutils and coreutils-dbgsym:

```
$ sudo apt-get install coreutils-dbgsym
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
coreutils-dbgsym is already the newest version (8.30-3ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.

$ apt-cache policy coreutils
coreutils:
  Installed: 8.30-3ubuntu2
  Candidate: 8.30-3ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 8.30-3ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: You don't have the actual source for the program of the C library installed in the expected location.

Comment: The problem is with this file `src/ls.c`.

What do you have there? I don't see an implementation of something called ls.c in this tutorial.

Did you implement your own `ls` command?